# I need to use variables from two controllers in one view

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5.8

I need to use $post and $post1 in one view(show.blade.php), but when I connect $post variable on the page, the second one $post1 is undefined.

first controller-

```
public function index()
{
   $posts1 = Komentar::all();
    return view('prispevky.show', compact('posts1'));
}
```

second one-

```
public function index()
{

$posts = Post::latest()->paginate();


return view('prispevky.index', compact('posts'));
}
```

show.blade.php page-

```
{{$post1->obsah}}
{{$post->id}}
```

https://www.codepile.net/pile/JKWEpA6B - more code

Comment: You have two different views.. show and index are not the same view.

Comment: But I am using the $post in my show.blade.php page aswell.

Comment: you have to return from the controller the view with all the variables that you are going to use

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ  Can you make little code example?

Comment: yep, I wrote an answer